# How to disable /grey out parent window once pop window is open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code that will trigger a pop-up window when user clicks an icon in a table. Now, I would like to greyout/disable the parent window once a pop-up has been opened, and then return the parent window to normal once the pop-up is closed.

Even though this question was already asked before, I have tried with some examples given in SO, but I didn't get expected result, so please help me.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".popup-trigger", function (event) {
    alert("i am inside");

    // var currentrow = $(this).closest("tr");
    // var sino = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text(); // get SI no from checkbox
    // alert(sino);

    var scrollTop = '';
    var newHeight = '100';

    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        scrollTop = $( window ).scrollTop();
        newHeight = scrollTop + 100;
    });
    
    $('.popup-trigger').click(function(e) {
        alert( $('#grn').val());
        $("#sino").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[1].textContent);
        $("#iname").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[2].textContent);
        $("#recqty").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[4].textContent);

        e.stopPropagation();
        
        if (jQuery(window).width() < 767) {
            $(this).after( $( ".popup" ) );
            $('.popup').show().addClass('popup-mobile').css('top', 0);

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('.popup').offset().top
            }, 500);
        } else {
            $('.popup').removeClass('popup-mobile').css('top', newHeight).toggle();
        };
    });

    $('html').click(function() {
        $('.popup').hide();
    });

    $('.popup-btn-close').click(function(e){
        $('.popup').hide();
    });

    $('.popup').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup">
    SI no:        <input type ="text" readonly="readonly" id = "sino" class="inp"/><br>
    Item name:    <input type ="text" readonly="readonly" id="iname" class="inp"/><br>
    Received Qty: <input type ="text" readonly="readonly" id ="recqty" class="inp"/><br>
    <span class="popup-btn-close">close</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap for this project? If you are, there's already a built-in "modal" feature, ready for you to use.

Comment: No i am not using that